# Prove product of two positive proper fractions is always smaller than either of them

Tags: fractions

How would one go about setting out a formal proof that the product of two positive proper fractions will generate a positive number less than either of them?

(This is not homework, rather curiosity how to formally prove something that is generally taken as self-evident)

Comment: A positive proper fraction is always between $0$ and $1$.  It is a well known property of $<$ that if $0<x<1$ and $0<y$ then $0<xy<y$.  See [properties of ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field).

Comment: Assume $r,s < 1$ and assume that $rs \ge r$. Because they are positive dividing by $r$ we get $s \ge 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have proof simply.  But I want to offer a more complicated proof (way more complicated than necessary), but that reveals the structure of "proper fractions" and how that structure leads to your property in question.

A positive proper fraction $A$ can be written in the form
$$ A = \frac{a}{a + \epsilon} \mbox{ where } 0< a, \epsilon \in \mathbb{N}.  $$
Note that $0 < A < 1$.

So consider two proper fractions, $A$ and $B$, and their product $P$:
$$ P = AB = \frac{a}{a + \epsilon_1} \left( \frac{b}{b + \epsilon_2} \right) = \frac{ab}{ab + ( a\epsilon_2 + b\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2)}. $$

Firstly we can see that the product is proper positive, $0 < P < 1$.

To check that $P<A$, note that $P/A = B < 1$. Similarly $P<B$ since $P/B = A < 1$.

Comment: Thanks this is the type of proof I was looking for.
I'm still not following the last line. I can see this proves that P < 1, but how does it prove that P < A and P < B?

Comment: $P/A < 1$ implies $P<A$.  Because a smaller number divided by a larger number is less than $1$